# Tyre recommendations for 20mm inner width

Tags: tire, product-rec, tyre-width

I decided to purchase some new tubeless ready rims which have 20mm inner rim width. I was wondering if anyone had any tyre recommendations that would be compatible with these rims? I intend on running the rims with tubes initially. Preferably a set of tyres which can be taken on and off the rim relatively easily would be great.

I thought GP5000s clinchers would be great, however these have not been recommended by the rim manufacturer due to the right fit. They suggested I check out Schwalbe but I’m open to other suggestions. I’m hoping to also use clincher tyres as opposed to tubeless ready tyres since they will hopefully seat much easier on the rim.

Comment: Does the manufacturer have any information about compatible tires/sizes in their documentation? For example here from [Schwalbe](https://www.schwalbe.com/files/schwalbe/userupload/Images/FAQ/reifen_felgen_2020/Reifen_Felgenkombinationen_2020_EN.pdf) featuring both their and ETRTROs recommendations. This suggests you shouldn't go lower than 25 mm with 20 mm internal width, probably better 28 mm. BTW.: Are we talking about hookless rims?

Comment: @DoNuT these are going to be tubeless ready hooked rims. I saw the ETRTROs chart and probably will be looking for a 25mm or 28mm tyre. There’s just so many options. I was a bit confused by the wheel manufacturer saying no to GP5000 when they should be compatible according to ETRTRO. I’m just really after a tyre that I can take on and off the rim myself to replace a tube on a ride. I thought having a clincher tyre would ensure I could make the tyre seat without having to use a track pump or CO2.

Comment: @DoNuT to follow up, I found that the manufacturer recommends 25mm-28mm tyres and appeals to the ETRTRO standards. I feel as though the GP5000s should be fine then? They do say they are a tight fit which is my only worry. I don’t see how the fit would be any different to other brands though since the diameter of the tyre would be the same?

Comment: This [test](https://www.bikeradar.com/reviews/continental-grand-prix-5000-s-tr-review) states that the GP5000S *TR* in 25 fits a 21mm internal width maximum, so maybe the 28 would be a better choice. Take it with a grain of salt but I think, with _hooked_ rims in compatible dimensions, there is not so much to worry about as for hookless, which often is a delicate topic and narrow tire combinations often don't work so well because of the 5 bar ETRTRO max. pressure recommendation.

Comment: 28 mm really looks better. It is also more modern, faster and more comfortable to use wider tyres. Even for professional road racing. The manufacturer is probably concerned that in their tests it is hard to got the GP5000 tyre on and off the rim. If that is true, you may want to look for something easier to put on and off. Do I understand correctly that you want to use the tyres with an inner tube?

Comment: One more thing about GP5000s. If you want to run it with tubes only, you could go for the _clincher_ variant (I think it is a bit older than the TL/TR variants but still a decent tire) - no thick tubeless beads and that'll probably mount a bit easier, too... since you write _with tubes initially_, I assume you want a tubeless-ready tire, though?

Comment: @DoNuT I’m hoping to just use a clincher tyre actually! I’m hoping this will make the seating on the bead a bit easier. I was initially going to get the GP5000s but they said it’s a tight fit. I don’t see how though… maybe they were getting confused with the tubeless ready variant?

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава you are correct in that I want to use a tube in a tubeless ready tyre

Answer (score 3):

One answer is that any tire can be a tight fit to a tubeless rim. This is how they stay on. However, learning to use the bead well in the center of the rim is a key part of the learning process - even if you use tubes, because that’s how we get the tires mounted.

Another answer is that if the rim was made in or after 2021 and if it complies to the latest ETRTO specification for tubeless tires, then any of the current generation tubeless tires should be able to fit securely but also not too tightly. You will need to beware of putting too wide a tire on, e.g. technically a 25mm internal width rim should take no less than a 29mm tire unless the manufacture specifically tested for compatibility. Anyway, consider the link that DoNuT posted in comments. The GP 5000 was always thought to be hard to mount, and yet the reviewer said they got it on without tools.

If the manufacturer issues an explicit instruction and you confirmed that it refers to the particular model you have on hand, then you should respect it unless you know what you are doing and preferably you have reliable information otherwise. However, the existence of such instructions raises concern for me that the rim doesn’t correspond to the ETRTO standard. This standard gives a nominal dimension and a tolerance for the bead seat diameter. You normally would think it’s 622mm. To the manufacturers, it is actually 621.95mm +/- 0.5mm. The standard governs other rim dimensions, e.g. the height of the sidewalls above the bead seat (G-height). And there’s a corresponding standard for tires.

If you have a non-ETRTO rim, then if it is hooked, it should still be fine to use with tubes. If it’s hookless, then maybe that rim should not have been manufactured - if you look on YouTube, you should be able to find a video of a blowoff of a GP 5k from an Extralite rim that the owner later discovered was not made to ETRTO standards, with that information not being communicated clearly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I believe the rims that I have purchased are to ETRTO standards as it says that any ETRTO compatible tyre (tubeless ready or clincher) may be fitted onto the rim. I have sent them an email specifically about the GP5000 as these have been reliable in the past, however initially they seemed to not recommend it due to the tight fit on the rim and hence have made it incompatible. I'll see what they have to say back.

Comment: I'm not sure if you would know, but would I be correct in saying that running a clincher with a tube will have a much better chance of the tyre seating compared to with a tube and tubeless ready tyre? I really just want to make my life as easy as possible.

Comment: @JayP you’re over thinking this.

Comment: @PaulH I know I probably am. I just have had issues in the past being stuck on the side of the road with tubeless ready wheels being unable to replace the tube. That’s why I’m asking for recommendations.

Comment: @JayP If you are so intent on the Conti GP tyres, why not get different rims? There are very few genuinely "game changing" products: you can find other wheels with an equal spec that actually do what you want.

Comment: @JayP In worst case, there are plenty of other manufacturers alternatives and as long as you shop within the same tier of tires, attributes such as rolling resistance, handling and puncture protection will be in the same ballpark. I must admit that I got the GP5000 mostly because the tan sidewall variant looks neat. Before, I had a more middle-ground Vittoria Corsa Control which was easier to mount, but I should add that my rims are narrower and I think my setup isn't TLR. In case of doubt, read some reviews and look up for remarks regarding installation.